# Scalable clustering algorithm in spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have 70,000 elements, the elements must be used to a unsupervised learnii also tried use ding job, i tried use K-means and Bisecting K-means to make the job run, i use TF-IDF to create an input RDD to the algorithm, i also tried to use  dimensionality reductors,especifically SVD and PCA, but the reductors don't work, i always get heap space problems, this is my configuration:

```
spark-submit \
--class myclass \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 1000mb \
--executor-memory 1000mb \
--num-executors 5 \
--driver-java-options "-Dcommons.config.resource=configs/homolog-       jobs.properties -Dhbase.build.file.location=PATH" 
--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=- Dcommons.config.resource=configs/homolog-jobs.properties -Dhbase.build.file.location=PATH' \
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcommons.config.resource=configs/homolog-jobs.properties -Dhbase.build.file.location=PATH' \
/path to my jar \
10 (number of cluster)
```

Comment: Spark clustering is incredibly bad. Use other tools, such as ELKI, you will be surprised about the performance differences!

Comment: Thank you for answering, about elki, i can use this tool in production? I can integrate Elki with Hortonworks Data Platform? Elki is scalable?

Comment: Clustering is *never* scalable, and *never* integratable, because it's too unreliable. Running it once may give you a good result, running it next week on new data it may fail. It's not meant to be used automatic.

Comment: Ok Anony-Mousse, thanks again, i will try other solutions.